# Unable to change the Shipping Address Label and to add drop-down value under text box in checkout page Magento 2.x

Tags: magento2

I was trying to change the Checkout page shipping address fields label but I can't find the files where I can change them.

I have checked all the files of shipping address files but I am unable to change the Label text.

Please Magento 2.x default checkout shipping address fields label and also check my desire text label for shipping address.

Is there anyone to help me out.

Please check my screenshots below.
1. Magento 2.x Default Checkout page url: https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/22374102/25710262/92983352-310d-11e7-8676-6c333a13e6f8.png

2. Custom Checkout screenshot url link: https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/22374102/25710264/92d236ec-310d-11e7-9a3e-fe82416e7041.png

Comment: Did you tried using translation? Or you want to change hard code?

Comment: I have tried with Translate but it's not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily change label text using translation. [You can follow official tutorial](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/translations/theme_dictionary.html)

Now I am going to create a module called **SR_Checkout**. So make sure this module is load after **Magento_Checkout** module.
So module.xml looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="SR_Checkout" setup_version="2.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Checkout"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

Now create a **i18n** directory under your module path is **SR/Checkout/i18n**

Create **SR/Checkout/i18n/en_US.csv** and content should be

```
City,Test City
Country,Test Country
State/Province,Test State/Province
```

**OR**

You can overwrite in theme level translation. 
[Here is an example](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.1/app/design/frontend/Magento/luma/i18n/en_US.csv)

So go to your theme, open **app/design/frontend/YourVendor/YourTheme/i18n/en_US.csv** and put following content

```
"City","Test1 City"
"Country","Test1 Country"
"State/Province","Test1 State/Province"
```

Clear cache.

Comment: I have used like City,Division
"State/Province","District" but it working on my local machine, not on the live server. I need the the file path where I can override it.

Comment: Check updated answer

Comment: Can anyone tell me the Shipping address Form path to custom?

Comment: Do you use magento 2 default checkout or custom extension?

Comment: This is checkout field generator -> https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.1/app/code/Magento/Checkout/Block/Checkout/LayoutProcessor.php#L129

Comment: I am using Magento 2.x default checkout.

Comment: Did you clear all cache? I tested all translation working fine.

Comment: Yes, I have cleared all the cache. I want to get Address form file to add the custom address. like my screenshot above